# Count the number of google search a user made

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, numbers

i'm creating a small chrome extension and i need to get or simply count the  number of searches a user made on google, is there a way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: This is too board. Please read the help on asking good question

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome history API
Sample below will show top 10 recent visits

```
chrome.history.search({text: 'google', maxResults: 10}, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(page) {
        console.log(page.url);
    });
});
```